supabase error when trying to upload my file
when i try to upload my file into supabase which i'm locally hosting i get this error below:
Failed to upload Australia.pmtiles: tus: unexpected response while creating upload, originated from request (method: POST, url: http://localhost:8000/storage/v1/upload/resumable, response code: 500, response text: Something went wrong with that request The file system does not support extended attributes or has the feature disabled. , request id: n/a)
i want to upload my file and i expect it to load without error

What OS and storage backend are you using?
In the past there have been problems on MacOS when using osxfs + local disk as storage backend as docker on MacOS in that combination didn't (doesn't?) support extended attributes
See also https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/3902

I'm using Monterey as the OS , just looked into the link you sent and I guess it's best to use s3
